# Trouble with sound effects at Onclick (Null Pointer and MediaPlayer Warning

Tags: android, audio, nullpointerexception, media-player

I have created a simple Ukulele tuner (The market I think lacks a visually pleasing and extremely simple tuner).

Any how, firstly, through the developer console I can see that there is a Null Pointer Exception at the Button Onclick Events. I have not been able to recreate this, however it has been reported four times.

Secondly, looking at the log while using the app I can see this warning;

```
E/MP3Extractor(68): Unable to resync. Signalling end of stream.
```

This entry here [MediaPlayer array causing null pointer in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6977511/mediaplayer-array-causing-null-pointer-in-android) seems to be along the same lines.

How it works.
Through the use of radio buttons the user selects either to play a single note or a continuous note. I have created a subroutine called StopMediaPlayer that stops, resets and instantiates the MediaPlayers again. This was used because I could never seem to stop the continuous play back but only pause it.

Is the warning and the NullPointerException related? Is there a more efficient/better means of stopping MediaPlayer that will mean that I wont have to re instantiate the notes every time.

Thank You

One of the offending Onclicks

```
Button gButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.gButton);
    gButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() 
    {
        public void onClick(View v)
        {
            if (singleRadio.isChecked() == true)
            {
                StopMediaPLayer();
                gNote.setLooping(false);
                gNote.start();


            }
            else if (contRadio.isChecked() == true)
            {
                StopMediaPLayer();
                gNote.setLooping(true);
                gNote.start();
            }

        }
    });
```

Stop Media Player Subroutine

```
public void StopMediaPLayer()
{
    Log.i("UkuleleTuner", "Stop Media Player");
    gNote.setLooping(false);
    cNote.setLooping(false);
    eNote.setLooping(false);
    aNote.setLooping(false);

    gNote.stop();
    cNote.stop();
    eNote.stop();
    aNote.stop();

    gNote.reset();
    cNote.reset();
    eNote.reset();
    aNote.reset();

    gNote = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.g_note);
    cNote = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.c_note);
    eNote = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.e_note);
    aNote = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.a_note);
}
```